# Pressure Testing plumbing - pressure drop over night

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, testing

I'm pressure testing some PEX before I close in the walls.  I pumped in 80psi of air around noon yesterday and it was about 60 degrees F.  Was a solid 80psi from when i filled to to 11pm (11 hours). The pressure in the lines went from 80psi to 74psi over night.  It got down to about 50 Degrees F.

Could I loose 4psi to the air getting cold?  I Have there is probably 50' of 3/4" PEX and 20' of 1/2" PEX in the closed system.